# Word stronger in meaning than believe

Tags: word-choice

I am looking for a word stronger in meaning than the word "believe"
for example:
I trust the results of my analysis 100% so I believe that the following blabla, ... will happen.

Are there any other words than " believe" to describe this strong feeling of trust?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am confident that

I can definitively state that

I am convinced that

I am certain that